# Facebook Feed Dialog Post has can_share set to false

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, feed

i'm using FB feed dialog to share contents on user diary.
Now i want to get like,share and comments count of this post.
To reach this scope, i'm using FQL query:

```
    select like_info, share_info, comment_info from stream where post_id='xxxxxxxxx'
```

obtaining this result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_info": {
        "can_like": true, 
        "like_count": 2, 
        "user_likes": true
      }, 
      "share_info": {
        "can_share": false, 
        "share_count": 0
      }, 
      "comment_info": {
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_count": 1, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to know why "can_share" option is set to false, and how (or if) i can change it to true!

Thanks.